# Finding J-invariant of Legendre form of Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

PROBLEM: Put the Legendre equation $y^2 = x(x − 1)(x − λ)$ into Weierstrass
form and use this to show that the j-invariant is
j = $2^8\frac{(λ2 − λ + 1)^3}{λ^2(λ − 1)^2}$ .

Recall: 
Weierstrass equation form:   E: y^2 = x^3 + Ax +B
and

J(E) = 1728$\frac{4A^3}{4A^3+27B^2}$

Attempt: 
$y^2 = x^3 + (-\lambda-1)x^2 + \lambda x$

Now I'm having trouble transforming this into Weierstass form. What would be the way to go for transforming this equation? $x^2 = x_1$ would not work. Idk..

Comment: I would try $x'=u^2x+r$, $y'=u^3 y$ for some suitable constants $u,r$.

Comment: So then x = $\frac{x'}{u^2}$ and y = $\frac{y'}{u^3}$.
Plugging that in did not get that $x^2$ to disappear. I'm sure there's a simple transformation that I'm not just not thinking of. It's one of those once someone shows me I'll feel dumb.

Comment: You are to find a suitable value of $r$. It may be the case that you can assume that $u=1$, I'm not sure.

Comment: Like Jyrki says, a transformation of the form $x'=x+r$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if a curve is given by $Y^2=X^3+AX^2+BX+C$, a change of variables $Y=y$ and $X=x-A/3$ will provide a model for the curve of the form $y^2=x^3+A'x+B'$.

The reason is that
$$X^3+AX^2+\cdots = (x-A/3)^3 + A(x-A/3)^2+\cdots$$
and the coefficient in $x^2$ is given by $3(-A/3)+A=0$.